# Data structure that has constant time for insertion, contains, remove and getting elements by index

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a large data set of `Person` objects which are queued up in a list. I want the data structure to be able to do the following operations efficiently.

1. Add a `Person` at the end of the queue.
2. Remove the first `Person`.
3. Find whether a particular `Person` exists, if so, remove it and put it at the end of the queue.
4. Get a particular `Person` by its position.

Is it possible to have O(1) time for all of these operations?
So far I have come up with two ways, but they are not optimal.

1. `ArrayList<Person>` + `HashMap<Person, Integer>`

   The `HashMap` stores the index of the `Person` objects. This gives O(n) time for operation 2 and 3 (removing element in the `ArrayList`)
2. `ArrayDeque<Person>` / `LinkedList<Person>`

   They give O(1) for first 2 operations, but O(n) for the last two.

Space complexity must not be larger than O(n) in my case. Operation 4 is less intensive, so I could tolerate a slightly inefficient way to do this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont think that you can reduce the complexity for last two operations. For searching a list the time complexity is definitely going to be O(n) until and unless the the list is sorted.

Comment: @Karan Searching in O(1) time is possible with hash tables. I think at least three of the operations can be in O(1), if not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that requirement 3 means "find a person by some key" (e.g. its last name)?

I have a strong feeling you can't have all those requirements in O(1), not even amortized time (such a thing would be well-known). But you can have all of them in O(log N). You'd have to start with an implementation of a red-black tree (std::map in C++, I believe this is SortedMap in Java), and modify the node structure to keep the count of all nodes in its sub-tree. This would give you O(log N) access by index, as well as O(log N) insert and removal anywhere in the tree. Finding a person by some key can be done in O(1) by an external hash table (of red-black tree nodes).

If you're ok with O(N) for requirement 4, then I'd suggest using something like LinkedHashMap in Java, which gives you requirements 1 to 3 in O(1), while req. 4 can be done by iterating, in O(N).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Didn't know that using red-black tree can get element by index in O(log n). And thanks for mentioning LinkedHashMap as well. I must have overlooked it before.

Answer (score 2):

If the question hasn't been tagged `java`, but `c++`, a combination of `std::deque` and `std::unordered_map` would *almost* suffice. I say almost because third request is rather complicated and I don't see how to do it in `O(1)` combined with other three.

`std::unordered_map` has its equivalent in Java, `HashMap`, but what `std::deque` provides and `ArrayDeque` doesn't, is `O(1)` random access -> your request number four. Even though it [has already been discussed](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2014-February/024947.html), this feature is still missing in `ArrayDeque`, but I suppose it wouldn't be so hard to manually add it. After all, `std::deque` is merely a vector with pointers to the fixed-size buffers.

First two operations are `O(1)` in any decent deque implementation. As per request number three, `HashMap` (or `std::unordered_map`) would give you an information whether a particular `Person` exists in `O(1)` time, and you can put it at the end with the same complexity. Removing is a problem because other elements have to be shifted and that cannot be obtained in `O(1)` by using this strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, O(n) removal would not be optimal in my case. Anyway, good point on the `std::deque`.